# What kind of kale is this?

Tags: botany, species-identification, vegetable

I'm from Pennsylvania and I used to get this kale all the time at the grocery store, but I moved to the West Coast recently and can't find it anywhere! It looks exactly like this photo:

[image]
<sup>*Image source: http://www.specialtyproduce.com/produce/Kale_Purple_764.php*</sup>.

I've seen this referred to as purple kale, salad savoy, and flowering kale, but I don't think any of those are 100% accurate. The purple kale I've found here is tougher and more bitter, with spikier leaves and a more reddish color, and it doesn't come as a bunch like this but as individual stems. Does anyone know exactly what this variety is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a variant of kale, part of the genus *Brassica*. I think you'd call this particular variant redbor or purple, bluntly, but you could go further because kale is often classified by the type of leaf. So in your picture, curly 'redbor' or 'purple' kale.

This is your specific name: *Brassica oleracea* Acephala Group.

(just sort of look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica_oleracea))